# multiple definitions of background image with gradient for different browsers collide or overwrite and cause dysfunction

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, bootstrap-4

In an Angular 2 (2.4) project using bootstrap 4 I have encountered a problem with multiple definitions of background image with gradient for different browsers in a navigation side bar:

HTML:

```
<div  class="mysidebar">
    <ul class="nav-sidebar">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="side-icon-dashboard nav-link">
          <br />
          <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/r-report']" class="side-icon-r nav-link">
          <br />
          <span>R Report</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/u-report']" class="side-icon-u nav-link">
          <br />
          Usage Report
        </a>
      </li>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="side-icon-m nav-link">
          <br />
          M Report
        </a>
      </li>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="side-icon-s nav-link">
        <br />
        S Report
      </a>
      </li>
      <div class="divider"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.mysidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 56px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  //display: inline-block;
  //padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color:#1887CA;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;

  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(112,47,138) 0%, rgb(0,159,219) 100%);

  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(112,47,138) 0%, rgb(0,159,219) 100%);
  //background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(112,47,138) 0%, rgb(0,159,219) 100%);

  ul.nav-sidebar {
    //margin-right: -21px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    //margin-left: -20px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    //background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(112,47,138) 0%, rgb(0,159,219) 100%);
    li {
      list-style-type: none !important;
      a {
        color: white;
      }
    }
  }

  div.divider {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    opacity: 0.102;
    width: 180px;
    height: 1px;
  }

  li {
    text-align: center;
    &.active {
      background-color: #eeeeee;
      a {
        color: #1887CA;
      }
    }
  }
```

When running in a chrome browser the gradient does not take effect, unless the last definition is:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(112,47,138) 0%, rgb(0,159,219) 100%);
```

It seems one defenition overwrites otheres and only when the last one is relevant to wanted browser it would work.

Thus, for firefox it works only when the last line is the one with -moz-linear-gradient:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(112,47,138) 0%, rgb(0,159,219) 100%);
```

How can it work as desired: that the order does not count?
What is causing this?

Comment: Using unprefixed seems to be ok these days [Can I use: linear-gradient](https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great! Indeed worked like a charm

Comment: To be precise it worked by omitting the prefix and updating the degrees:  background-image: linear-gradient( 0deg, rgb(112,47,138) 0%, rgb(0,159,219) 100%);

Comment: Awesome, I usually get away with using the standard syntax and a backup solid color just in case. [Additional resource regarding Gradients for reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)